# Or in Java if statements

Tags: java, if-statement

In Java, is there a way to do ors in if statements?  I a beginner programmer in Java and no previous programming experience, so I am a bit of a noob.  I know you can do &&, but then everything has to be true, but I only need one to be true, and I want to do this in a better way than a bunch of if statements next to each other.

Ex:
      Is there a more simple/compact way to do this:

```
        if(num == 1)
        {
              System.out.println("that is a number")
        }
        if(num == 2)
        {
              System.out.println("that is a number")
        }
```

Comment: || is the or operator.

Comment: Please consider seeing oracle website http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html

Comment: Is google broken?

Comment: Make sure you're using `==` instead of `=`.
`==` is the comparison operator whereas `=` is the assignment operator

Answer (score 2):

`||` is logical or.

```
if(num == 1 || num == 2)
```

Also you need to use `==` for equality. In java `=` is always assignment.

Answer (score 2):

This is the correct way:

```
if (num == 1 || num == 2) {
    System.out.println("that is a number");
}
```

In Java, `||` is the short-circuit OR operator. And please notice: comparisons are performed with the `==` operator, a single `=` is for assignment. Take a look at this page on the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use "or" in Java `if` statements.  Use the `||` operator.

And incidentally, use `==`, not `=` to compare numeric values in Java.  The `=` operator is the assignment operator; `==` tests if two numeric values are equal.

Comment: I just forgot the second =. I was typing fast. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the || operator for the OR statement, so your code would look like this:

```
if(num == 1 || num == 2)
{
    System.out.println("that is a number");
}
```

The println will be executed if num is equal to 1 OR is equal to 2.
ALSO: remember that "=" is different to "==": the first one is the assignment operator and is used to store a value in a variable, like:

```
int num = 1;
```

the second is the one you would probably want to use and it checks if the value on the left is equal to the value on the right.

Have a look at this page for a list of operators used in java:
[Java operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html)